# Extracting elements from a list in to a new list

Tags: list-manipulation

Currently I have a list such that,

```
f1 = {{x_1,y_1},{x_2,y_2},...,{x_n,y_n},
      {x_1,y_n+1},{x_2,y_n+2},...,{x_n,y_n'}
      {x_1,y_n'+1},{x_2,y_n'+2},...,{x_n,y_n''}};
```

Where the number of elements until $ x $ repeats is knowable and the number of x_1's is knowable, say $ i $.

I want to make a new list from the list f1 such that,

```
f2 = {{x_1, ((y_1 + y_n+1 + ... )/i)},
      {x_2, ((y_2 + y_n+2 + ... )/i)}, ...}
```

Im sorry if this is question is ill formed and if you need further clarification please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: First off, writing the $x_j$s that way is very confusing, since `x_j` is Mathematica syntax for a pattern. It's also not clear how $n$, $n'$ and $n''$ relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` `First` to collect the pairs in an `Association`. Then `KeyValueMap` to calculate your final form.

```
f = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x1, y4}, {x2, y5}, {x3, y6}, {x1, y7}, {x2, y8}, {x3, y9}};


KeyValueMap[
 Function[{key, value},
  {key, Mean[Last /@ value]}],
 GroupBy[f, First]]

(* {{x1, 1/3 (y1 + y4 + y7)}, {x2, 1/3 (y2 + y5 + y8)}, {x3, 1/3 (y3 + y6 + y9)}} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
f = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x1, y4}, {x2, y5}, {x3, y6}, {x1, y7}, {x2, y8}, {x3, y9}};

x = Union[f[[All, 1]]];

y = Mean /@ Transpose@Partition[f[[All, 2]], Length@x];

Transpose[{x, y}]
```

> {{x1, 1/3 (y1 + y4 + y7)}, {x2, 1/3 (y2 + y5 + y8)}, {x3, 1/3 (y3 + y6
>   + y9)}}

Comment: I realize my solution was essentially the same as yours (because I didn't read yours carefully enough), so I've deleted mine, and I'll leave this here as a comment: `n = Length@Union@f[[All, 1]]; Transpose[{f[[ ;; n, 1]], Mean@Partition[f[[All, 2]], n]}]`. Basically, you can take advantage of the way that `Mean` threads over lists so that you don't have to `Map` it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip with map and mean :)